# Adding Bookmarklet Javascript to Block?

Tags: javascript, html, drupal, bookmarklet

Hello i've been trying to do this for about 2 years. I think it worked once but ever since then i just can't make it happen again. Im adding this code to a block-

```
    <a href="javascript:u=document.location.href;t=document.title; s=window.getSelection();
void(window.open("http://onlinebanter.com/node/add/web2ob?edit[title]="+escape(t)+'&edit[body_field][body]='+escape(s)+'&edit[field_link][0][url]='+escape(u),'_blank','width=600,height=500,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes'));">Test</a>
```

When i try to drag that to my browser the url comes out as so-

```
    javascript:u=document.location.href;t=document.title;s=window.getSelection();void(window.open(
```

I am using the Full HTML filter option and isnt adding line breaks or anything. If i edit the link in my browser and add just

```
javascript:u=document.location.href;t=document.title;s=window.getSelection();void(window.open("http://onlinebanter.com/node/add/web2ob?edit[title]="+escape(t)+'&edit[body_field][body]='+escape(s)+'&edit[field_link][0][url]='+escape(u),'_blank','width=600,height=500,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes'));
```

Things work great. I have looked about and have asked here previously
http://drupal.org/node/235074

I must just be missing something so simple as it seems the whole internet doesnt have this problem. All help appreciated thanks.

Reg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the double-quotes in your window.open() call.

The browser thinks that you're closing the `href="javascript... "`

Replace the double quotes in `"http://onlinebanter.com/node/add/web2ob?edit[title]="` with single quotes.

Comment: Sryy John i totally missed this. im away travelling at the moment. I appreciate your response. Let me go try.....a brilliant john thats fixed it. Thats a long time problem. thank you very much